# Shopware 6 cms block for registration page

Tags: shopware, shopware6

In Shopware 6.5, I have created a new page layout for the product page.
In my product page layout i added a CMS text block with a CMS element containing static text .
I would like to add the same block and element to my registration page so when i change the text for the product page, it will be changed automatically for the registration page also.

Can i modify the registration page twig template Resources/views/storefront/page/account/register/index.html.twig to add the same CMS block and CMS element from the product page ?